# If you have an array with repeated numerical data, determine which is the prime that is repeated the most

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm, primes

I would like to see to roadmap to solve this algorithm I was trying:

```
cd = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
A = []
for i in range(cd):
 el = input("")
 A.append(el)

c = 0 
while c < cd:
 cm = 0
 c2 = 1
 while c2 < A[c]:
     if A[c] % c2 == 0:
         cm  = cm + 1  
     c2 += 1
 if cm == 2:
     P1 = A[c]
 c += 1
```

But then I got stuck. Notice how the style the code is written I would like to see the same style for the solution

restrictions:
dictionaries are not allowed

Comment: What do you mean exactly by “without using Python methods”?  The term “raw algorithm” doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: @Samwise closest to pseudo code as possibe

Comment: If you aren't allowed to use dictionaries, I suppose I'd start by sorting the array, which you can do in O(nlogn).  Then you can iterate over the array, check each for primeness, count the number of identical items if it's prime (since all the identical items will be grouped after the sort), and keep track of the max as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a twist on the sieve of Eratosthenes by placing the count of numbers in the sieve instead of simple True/False flags.  Clearing the multiples of each factor out of the sieve will invalidate the counts for non-primes.  This will leave the sieve with number counts only on positions that are prime numbers:

```
A = [13, 70, 33, 83, 76, 41, 4, 38, 70, 56, 38, 65, 95,
     83, 85, 38, 92, 23, 30, 47]

# Setup Sieve of Eratosthenes for largest number
# prime flags contain count of corresponding number
isPrime = []
maxN    = -1
for n in A:
    if n > maxN:
        isPrime += [0] * (n - maxN)
        maxN = n
    isPrime[n] += 1

# perform sieve     
p   = 2
inc = 1 
while p*p <= maxN:
    if isPrime[p] >= 0:     # clear out counts for multiples of primes
        i  = p*p       
        while i <= maxN:
            isPrime[i] = -1
            i += p*inc
    p  += inc
    inc = 2

# find number that is prime and has highest count
prime = None
count = 0
for n in A:
    if isPrime[n] > count:
        prime = n
        count = isPrime[n]
```

output:

```
print("most frequent prime:", prime, " found", count, "time(s)")

most frequent prime: 83  found 2 time(s)
```

Alternatively, you could progressively eliminate the non primes from the list by performing divisor test on remaining elements. With the remaining list of only prime numbers, find the one with the highest count:

```
# remove non-primes
primes = A
p      = 2
inc    = 1
more   = True
while primes and more:
    more = False
    remaining, primes = primes, []
    for n in remaining:
        if n % p == 0: continue 
        primes.append(n)         
        if p*p <= n:
            more = True
    p  += inc
    inc = 2

# get highest count    
prime   = None
count   = 0
counted = []
for n in primes:
    if n in counted: continue
    counted.append(n)
    c = 0
    for m in primes:
        if m == n:
            c += 1
    if c > count:
        prime, count = n, c
```

Which method is faster depends on the data (largets number vs number of items, proportion of primes, ...)

*Note that I intentionally avoided using python built-in functions (len,range,max,...) and data structures (dictionary, set,...).  More efficient constructs could streamline and improve the code depending on what you are allowed to use.*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```py
def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    i = 3
    while i**2 <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 2
    return True


cd = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
A = []
for i in range(cd):
    el = int(input(""))
    A.append(el)

# Dictionary `prime_counts` will contain the number of times that each prime
# number appears in list `A`. The dictionary will have the following structure:
# - Keys: prime number
# - Values: number of times the prime number appears on list `A`
prime_counts = {}

for el in A:
    if is_prime(el):  # Check if number is prime
        # Add new key to the `prime_counts` dictionary if key doesn’t already
        # exist..
        if el not in prime_counts.keys():
            prime_counts[el] = 0
        # Add 1 to the prime counting
        prime_counts[el] += 1

# Finding which prime number repeats the most
max_count = max(prime_counts.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]) # Returns a tuple, like (139, 121)
# Where:
# - 139: is the prime number that repeats the most
# - 121: frequency that the number repeats

print(f"The prime number {max_count[0]:,} repeats most frequently: {max_count[1]:,}")
# Prints something like:
# "The prime number 139 repeats most frequently: 121"
```

### Testing

To test the solution, we'll use the `random` package, to generate 20,000 random numbers with values between 0 and 200.

```py
import random

cd = 20_000
A = [random.randint(0, 200) for _ in range(cd)]

prime_counts = {}
for el in A:
    if is_prime(el):
        if el not in prime_counts.keys():
            prime_counts[el] = 0
        prime_counts[el] += 1

max_count = max(prime_counts.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
print(f"The prime number {max_count[0]:,} repeats most frequently: {max_count[1]:,}")
# Prints:
# "The prime number 173 repeats most frequently: 127"
```

### Detailed Overview

We can breakdown the problem into steps:

1. Extract all prime numbers from the array.
2. Count the occurrences of each prime number.
3. Identify the prime number with the highest count.

The code you've started with isn't completely correct as it's trying to check the primality for every number in the list, but it doesn't keep track of the counts.

Defining the function `is_prime` helps us check whether a number is prime or not:

```py
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    i = 3
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 2
    return True
```

Next, we can modify your original code to create a list of prime numbers and
count their occurrences:

```py
cd = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
A = []
for i in range(cd):
    el = int(input(""))
    A.append(el)

prime_counts = {}
for el in A:
    if is_prime(el):
        if el not in prime_counts.keys():
            prime_counts[el] = 0
        prime_counts[el] += 1
```

Finally, using the `max` function we can find the prime number that occurs most often:

```py
max_count = max(prime_counts.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]) # Returns a tuple, like (139, 121)
# Note: kv stands for "key-value"
print(f"The prime number {max_count[0]:,} repeats most frequently: {max_count[1]:,}")
```